# Mojolicious API is disregarding the characters after " . " in the URL argument

Tags: api, perl, mojolicious

I have defined the following route in my code:

```
my $route = $r->any('/api')->to('API#');
$route->get('/get_data/:filename')->to('#submit_forms');
```

if the filename that I pass into the url is "foo123456.bar_baz.bz2", when I print the argument, I get: (for example http://example.com/api/get_data/foo123456.bar_baz.bz2

```
print Dumper($c->param('filename'));
# foo123456
```

Why is it cutting everything after the period?

Comment: From an API perspective, it seems weird to ask for a file by name rather than ask for a particular set of data in a particular format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `#` (or `*`) instead of `:` for your placeholder:

```
$route->get('/get_data/#filename')->to('#submit_forms');
```

Mojolicious has 3 kinds of placeholders:

- [Standard placeholders](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Standard-placeholders) (`:`) match anything but `/` and `.`.
- [Relaxed placeholders](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Relaxed-placeholders) (`#`) match anything but `/`.
- [Wildcard placeholders](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Wildcard-placeholders) (`*`) match anything.

Quoting the documentation of relaxed placeholders:

> They can be especially useful for manually matching file names with extensions